# Drawing in Unity using C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently have a WinForms C# application. I have a .txt file with GPS coordinates of some points (borders of buildings, roads etc.), and using `Graphics.FillPolygon` method in `System.Drawing` I am drawing these on a `Panel`. However, I got an idea that for what I am trying to do (it basically is a 2D game), a Unity 2D project would be more suitable and easy to use (mainly because of easier view handling using the cameras). However, I don't know how to do this drawing in it. I just need to somehow get these coordinates drawn in Unity, but I don't know how to do it.

Note: I already have some minor expirience with 3D in Unity, but I am a total newbie to 2D.
Thanks

Comment: the (implied) question is too broad - what exactly have you tried? What do you need to draw? Have you read through a 2d tutorial and considered using sprites?

Comment: From what I understood sprites are for premade bitmap graphics. I don't have that, I have just coordinates. What I'm looking for would be an equivalent of the `Graphics.FillPolygon` method. I was thinking of, let's say, creating a cube and drawing on it as a texture, but also no idea how.

Comment: To simplify things, let's say I would have three rectangles, I would have pixel coordinates of their edges, and would like to display them. How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no GDI/canvas implementation built into Unity. Drawing these in rastered 2D would be quite hard in Unity (basically putpixel level, or finding some third party library).

You have an alternative, though - you can draw these shapes in 3D, ignoring the third dimension. You have a few methods for this:

1. [Line renderers](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html) - this one will be the easiest, but forget about anything else than just drawing the outline, no fill etc.
2. [Make your own mesh](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) - This will let you use the geometry with your scene. It's an retained mode API (you init your geometry once)
3. [Use the GL namespace](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.html) - This will be only rendered on the screen, no interaction with the scene. It's an immidiate mode API (draw everything on every frame)